# Retrieve value from [FromBody]JObject POST method function without using model class in C#

Tags: c#, json, api, object, post

I am writing one Web API in the POST method. In that post, values will come as [FromBody]JObject. How can I take values from JObject without using any model class? I tried many ways, but not fixed my problem.
My code is,

```
 [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult SaveDetails([FromBody]JObject data)
    {
        try {

            JObject myJO = JObject.Parse(data.ToString());
            foreach (JProperty prop in myJO.Properties())
            {
                JObject childJO = (JObject)prop.Value;
              //  List<string> keys = childJO.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
                Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + ": " + prop.Value);
            }
            
            return Ok("Success ");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Ok("Failed. "+ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

And POST data is, `data:{"companyCode":"001","type":"LVR","id":"","LoginID":"MVC01","fromDate":"17 Mar 2021","toDate":"26 Mar 2021","reason":"The ","leaveType":"Annual leave","mode":"New"}`
My Postman is like,
[image: Postman screenshot]
Please give me a solution.

Comment: *I tried many ways, but not fixed my problem.* -- what is problem are you experiencing?  Also, does the POST body actually begin with `data:`?  Because, if it does, it isn't well-formed JSON.

Comment: my problem is like I need to get "companyCode" from that JSON string. but not getting. for that, I tried deserialization and all. but not getting value

Comment: @dbc i added postman screenshot also

Comment: Well can't you just do `(string)data["companyCode"]`

Comment: I tried this now, but it returns null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When data is sent in `JObject` format, why convert it to JObject again?

In this case, there is no need to re-edit and you only extract the data from the standard format. Delete this line: `JObject myJO = JObject.Parse (data.ToString ());`

For more information, you can refer to the following links

- [JObject Class](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)
- [Using JObject.Properties](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JObjectProperties.htm)

```html
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult SaveDetails([FromBody]JObject data)
{
    try
    {     
        foreach (JProperty prop in data.Properties())
        {
             foreach (JProperty property in o.Properties())
             {
                Console.WriteLine(property.Name + " - " + property.Value);
             }
             //or.....
             foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> property in data)
             {
                Console.WriteLine(property.Key + " - " + property.Value);
             } 
       }
       return Ok("Success ");
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       return Ok("Failed. "+ex.Message);
   }
}
```